# How can I generate FormControls dynamically inside a FormGroup?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, dynamic-arrays

I am receiving an object from the db that contains a few elements with the following format:

```
info = [{
    idcentro: "8227",
    namecentro: "Centro Paris", 
    address: "C/ Paris, 127",
    dias: [
      {
        dia: "0",
        horafinal: "06:00",
        horainicio: "17:00",
        salas: [
          {
            id: 0,
            nombre: "sala 1",
            intervalos: [
                ["09:00", "12:30", "10"],
                ["13:00", "21:30", "20"]
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        dia: "1",
        horafinal: "09:00",
        horainicio: "16:30",
        salas: [
          {
            id: 0,
            nombre: "sala 1",
            intervalos: [
                ["09:00", "12:30", "10"]
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            nombre: "sala 2",
            intervalos: [
                ["09:00", "20:30", "20"]
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        dia: "2",
        horafinal: "09:00",
        horainicio: "20:30",
        salas: [
          {
            id: 0,
            nombre: "sala 1",
            intervalos: [
                ["09:00", "12:30", "10"],
                ["12:45", "18:30", "15"]
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            nombre: "sala 2",
            intervalos: [
                ["09:00", "20:30", "20"]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }];
```

To work with those "dias" array and include inputs to modify each value in case the user wants to, I've manually created a FormGroup containing a formControl for each of those days (the real object contains up to 8 days).

```
    this.openingHoursForm = new FormGroup({
      day0OpeningTime: new FormControl(""),
      day0ClosingTime: new FormControl(""),
      day1OpeningTime: new FormControl(""),
      day1ClosingTime: new FormControl(""),
      day2OpeningTime: new FormControl(""),
      day2ClosingTime: new FormControl(""),
      day3OpeningTime: new FormControl(""),
      day3ClosingTime: new FormControl(""),
      day4OpeningTime: new FormControl(""),
      day4ClosingTime: new FormControl(""),
      day5OpeningTime: new FormControl(""),
      day5ClosingTime: new FormControl(""),
      day6OpeningTime: new FormControl(""),
      day6ClosingTime: new FormControl(""),
      day7OpeningTime: new FormControl(""),
      day7ClosingTime: new FormControl(""),
      day8OpeningTime: new FormControl(""),
      day8ClosingTime: new FormControl("")
    });
```

And then, in the HTML, I am creating two inputs for each of those those formControlNames:

```
<div class="dayOpeningHours" title="">
  <div>Day 0</div>
   <div class="opens">
     <label for="">De:
       <input class="form-control" type="time" formControlName="day0OpeningTime" name="day0OpeningTime">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class="closes">
     <label for="">A:
       <input class="form-control" formControlName="day0ClosingTime" name="day0ClosingTime">
     </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, this is becoming very unmaintainable. I have tried to create the markup (in the html) and formControlNames (in the ts) dynamically by looping through each "dia" of the 'dias' array, but I haven't achieved anything.

Is there a way I can generate the HTML and the declaration of those Form Controls inside the same formGroup? I have been reading about FormArray and AbstractControl but I can not really understand how to apply that to my code.

Can someone help me out or give me some tips to find the right documentation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better option would be to use a `FormArray` instead. You can also inject `FormBuilder` from `@angular/forms`

See Below

```js
constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) { }
diasForm = this.fb.group({
  openingHours: this.fb.array([])
})
get openingHours (): FormArray {
  return this.diasForm.get('openingHours') as FormArray;
}
```

The next task will be to create the form
Lets assume we have `dias` as an array

```js
dias = [
      {
        dia: "0",
        horafinal: "06:00",
        horainicio: "17:00",
      },
      {
        dia: "1",
        horafinal: "06:00",
        horainicio: "17:00",
      },
      ...
]
```

I have removed other properties for simplicity
In the `ngOnInit` we can set the value of our form

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.dias.forEach(dia => {
    this.openingHours.push(
      this.fb.group({
        horafinal: [dia.horafinal, []],
        horainicio: [dia.horainicio, []]
      })
    )
  })
}
```

In the Html

```html
<form [formGroup]='diasForm'>
  <div formArrayName='openingHours'>
    <div *ngFor='let item of openingHours.controls; let i = index' 
       [formGroupName]='i'>
         <input formControlName='horafinal' />
         <input formControlName='horainicio' />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The above should match the structure of our formGroup

`diasForm( [formGroup] ) ---> openingHours(formArray) ---> i ( [formGroup] ) ---> horafinal(formControl)`

Please see [this demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ygbds4)

This way you can have a dynamic number of days

Comment: Thank you for your answer Owen! But.... How would I implement this on the html side?

Comment: I have added a demo

Answer (score 1):

it's a large an complex object, but the "way" to control a json object is always the same: the properties simples are FormControl, the arrays are FormArrays and we use FormGroup to group controls.

So carefully, make four functions to create the form

```
  createForm(data: any = null) {
    data = data || {idcentro: null,namecentro: null,address: null,dias: null};
    return new FormGroup({
      idcentro: new FormControl(data.idcentro),
      namecentro: new FormControl(data.namecentro),
      address: new FormControl(data.address),
      dias: new FormArray(
        data.dias ? data.dias.map(x => this.createFormDias(x)) : []
      )
    });
  }
  createFormDias(data: any = null) {
    data = data || {dia: null,horafinal: null,horainicio: null,salas: null};
    return new FormGroup({
      dia: new FormControl(data.dia),
      horafinal: new FormControl(data.horafinal),
      horainicio: new FormControl(data.horainicio),
      salas: new FormArray(
        data.salas ? data.salas.map(x => this.createFormSalas(x)) : []
      )
    });
  }
createFormSalas(data: any = null) {
    data = data || { id: null, nombre: null, intervalos: null };
    return new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(data.id),
      nombre: new FormControl(data.nombre),
      intervalos:new FormArray(
        data.intervalos?this.createFormIntervalos(data.intervalos):[])
    });
  }
  createFormIntervalos(data:any=null)
  {
    return data.map(x=>new FormArray(x.map(y=>new FormControl(y))))
  }
```

And four functions more to get the formArrays

```
  get diasArray()
  {
    return this.form.get('dias') as FormArray
  }
  getSalas(index)
  {
    return this.diasArray.at(index).get('salas') as FormArray
  }
  getIntervalos(index1,index2)
  {
    return this.getSalas(index1).at(index2).get('intervalos') as FormArray
  }
  getHoras(index1,index2,index3)
  {
    return this.getIntervalos(index1,index2).at(index3) as FormArray
  }
```

To control in .html you need take account when a FormArray is a FormArray of FormGroups and when is a FormArray of FormControls

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>idcentro:<input formControlName="idcentro" /></div>
  <div>namecentro:<input formControlName="namecentro" /></div>
  <div>address:<input formControlName="address" /></div>
  <div formArrayName="dias">
    <div
      *ngFor="let grDias of diasArray.controls;let i=index"
      [formGroupName]="i"
    >
      <div>dia:<input formControlName="dia" /></div>
      <div>horafinal:<input formControlName="horafinal" /></div>
      <div>horainicio:<input formControlName="horainicio" /></div>
      <div formArrayName="salas">
        <div
          *ngFor="let grSalas of getSalas(i).controls;let j=index"
          [formGroupName]="j"
        >
          <div>id:<input formControlName="id" /></div>
          <div>nombre:<input formControlName="nombre" /></div>
          <div formArrayName="intervalos">
            <div
              *ngFor="let grIntervalos of getIntervalos(i,j).controls;let k=index"
            >
              <div [formArrayName]="k">
                <div *ngFor="let grHoras of getHoras(i,j,k).controls;let m=index">
                  <input [formControlName]="m">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The [ugly stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fpbbgt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

See that a FormArray of FormGroup we use

```
<div formGroupName="nameOfArray">
  <div *ngFor="let group of formArray.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
     ..here..
     <input formControlName="controlName">
  </div>
</div>
```

And a FormGroup of FormControls

```
<div formGroupName="nameOfArray">
  <div *ngFor="let group of formArray.controls;let i=index" >
     <input [formControlName]="i">
  </div>
</div>
```