# how to set value to form control array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In a formgroup we can patch or set value to control name like the ff  `this.modelForm.get('data1').patchValue('sample data')` , but what if the structure is an array of objects below like .

How do I set value or patch value to testData which is inside data1? . Thanks.

```
  "data1": [
            {
                "testData": "2022-04-01T00:00:00",
       
            }
        ]

.....
```

Comment: To access `testData` you would `data1[0]?.testData`.

Comment: To mannage an array in ReactiveForms you should use a FormArray. If your array is an array of object you use a FormArray of FormGroup, if your array is a simple array of "single elements" (string, number,boolean,Date) you use a FormArray of FormControls, see, eg. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64467079/how-can-i-generate-formcontrols-dynamically-inside-a-formgroup/64470664#64470664)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply as that

```js
myControl.setValue([...myControl.value, 'new value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to access that array and append to the array, like this.

this.modelForm.get('data1').push('add data here').

this will automatically take the new data and append it in the formControl.